# Observe an object we can't modify using Proxies

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

I want to observe an object using Proxies, an object from a game that I didn't make. I found this as the answer of another question:

```
var proxied = new Proxy(foo, {
    get: function(target, prop) {
        console.log({
            type: "get",
            target,
            prop
        })
        return Reflect.get(target, prop)
    },
    set: function(target, prop, value) {
        console.log({
            type: "set",
            target,
            prop,
            value
        })
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, value)
    }
})
```

If I change it, I have to do `proxied.bar = "Hello world"`. But I don't change it, the game does; and it doesn't do it like this. (it does `foo.bar` = ..., they don't use proxied...) So, what can I do to observe the array?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't a lot of options to be able to observe whether an object has changed or not. Previously we could use `Object.observe()` or `Object.watch()` but both of those have been deprecated and aren't reliable anymore.

Proxies are the only option, but obviously the game has to use the proxied object in order for trap to get hit.

I don't entirely know what you are able to do in terms of manipulating the original `foo` object, but instead of creating your `proxied` object, set `foo` to point to its own proxied self. In other words,

```
foo = new Proxy(foo, {
    get: function(target, prop) {
        console.log({
            type: "get",
            target,
            prop
        })
        return Reflect.get(target, prop)
    },
    set: function(target, prop, value) {
        console.log({
            type: "set",
            target,
            prop,
            value
        })
        return Reflect.set(target, prop, value)
    }
})
```

If you can manipulate the game's object directly like this, in the `get` and `set` traps you can pass in your own callback functions and be able to observe any changes in that object.

It is possible that you can't reassign `foo` (if it was declared with `const`). In that case, there is a work around but it's a little clunky and not synchronous like the above approach.

Essentially you could create a function that creates a cache of entries in the `foo` object, and at a given interval rechecks `foo` for any changes and executes any callback logic you specify. I can't be too specific because the implementation details really rely on `foo`'s structure (*e.g.*, its nestedness and what kind of objects it might contain--be they dates, function references, or the many other kinds of objects).

A basic implementation could look like this:

```
foo = { ... } // whatever kind of object foo is

function observeFoo() {
    const entries = Object.entries(foo);

    // initialize cache if we don't have one
    if (!observeFoo.cache) observeFoo.cache = {};

    // begin checking keys in cache
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        const [ key, value ] = entry;
        if (observeFoo.cache[key] !== value) {
            // do something regarding this change
        }

        // update cache
        observeFoo.cache[key] = value;
   });
}

setInterval(observeFoo, 1000);
```

Comment: I can't change it.

Comment: Isn't it easier to use a setInterval and just check if the old one isn't equal to the new?

Comment: `var fooVar = foo   
setInterval(() => {
        if(fooVar !== foo) {
            fooVar = foo
            console.log("change")
        }
})`

Comment: If you're only worried about that one property, then yes, it's simpler. I thought, from your original post, you were using a simple example for sake of clarity. If you literally only care about one property, your approach should work just fine. Mine is for a more general approach where you care about any change.

If you want to use your approach, I recommend setting your `setInterval()` call to a variable, so you can call `clearInterval()` on it if you ever want to stop observing.